# Access a class return from another class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, console

Hi I am fairly new to coding, I am trying to develop a simple DOTNET console application. The console asks for a username, one gets entered and assigned to the username field in the user class, then the same process for a password, and finally an permissions level given by an int.

There is a method in the user class that returns a string dependant on the int entered for the permissions level. How can I access that string to display it as part of my final string saying who is logged in in the console?

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace SmartWaste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter username:");
            var username = new User ();
            username.UserName = Console.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter password:");
            username.Password = Console.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter permissions level:");
            var PermissionLevelNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            username.PermissionsLevel(PermissionLevelNumber);

            Console.WriteLine($"Logged in as {username.UserName} with {username.Password} and {???PermissionsLevelreturn.string???}access level");       
        } 
    }
}
```

User.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SmartWaste
{
    public class User 
    {
        public string UserName;
        public string Password;
        public string Permissions;
        public string PermissionsLevel(int permissionslevel)
        {
            if(permissionslevel == 0)
            return "basic";
            if(permissionslevel == 1)
            return "Intermediate";
            if(permissionslevel == 2)
            return "Advanced";
            if(permissionslevel == 3)
            return "Admin"; 
            else
            return "No Permissions set";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That [missing] indent..

Comment: Anyway, non-void [*methods*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) return *values* which can be used (either directly in compound expressions, or assigned to variables, etc.): `var resultOfTheMethodCall = username.PermissionsLevel(PermissionLevelNumber); Use(resultOfTheMethodCall);`.

Comment: Going through a C# introductory book or tutorial would likely be beneficial to quickly learn core constructs.

Comment: Similar to what you're doing with that `int.Parse(..)` call (and a couple other place)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this two ways:

```cs
string strPerm = username.PermissionsLevel(PermissionLevelNumber);
Console.WriteLine($"Logged in as {username.UserName} with {username.Password} and {strPerm} access level");
```

Or you could condense it all into one line if you're feeling fancy:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Logged in as {username.UserName} with {username.Password} and {username.PermissionsLevel(PermissionLevelNumber)} access level");
```

You should also do a bit of research on [switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) and [enum types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) to help with some cleaner code as you're learning

Comment: @earlycoder No problem. These kinds of problems are not usually language specific, and are usually to do with lack of experience. Practice is the key